# Typo3, output alternative text of image in page/resources/media

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use fcObject to output a header image, the image is configured in page/resources/media:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.headerimage" />
```

---

```
lib.headerimage = IMAGE
lib.headerimage {
  file {
    # width = 550
    # height = 126
    import {
      data = levelmedia: -1, slide
      # wrap = uploads/media/|
      # listNum = 0
      listNum = rand
    }
    treatIdAsReference = 1
    required = 1
  }
  altText.data = page: title
  # wrap = <div id="keyvisual">|</div>
}
```

The above code doesn't output the alternative text of the image unfortunately, at the moment it takes the page title as alt text, and I can't figure out how to access the field "alternative".

I could use a viewhelper to output the image, like here:

```
<f:for each="{data.media}" as="file">
  <f:image image="{file}"/>
</f:for>
```

The benefit of using the image viewhelper is that it gives me the alt text of the image.

I prefer to use the lib though. I just can't figure out how to access the data of the image field "alternative" in typoscript.

Comment: It's correct that page title is used as alt text. You set `altText.data = page:title`

Comment: I don't want the page title as alt text, I want the actual alt text which I added to every image to be displayed as alt text

Comment: Yes, that's clear. I just want to say: It does, what you configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FILES` to get the expected result:

```
lib.headerimage = FILES
lib.headerimage {
    references {
        data = levelmedia: -1, slide
        listNum = rand
    }

    renderObj = IMAGE
    renderObj {
        file.import.dataWrap = {file:current:storage}:{file:current:identifier}
        altText.data = file:current:alternative
    }
}
```

Source: This example was taken from the [TypoScript Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html#usage-with-sliding).

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong field `page:title`. Use `file:current:alternative` instead.

```
lib.headerimage = IMAGE
lib.headerimage {
    file {
        import {
            data = levelmedia: -1, slide
            listNum = rand
        }
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        required = 1
    }
    altText.data = file:current:alternative
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In html source it outputs:     alt="Error: no file object"

Comment: Which TYPO3 version?

Comment: Typo3 version 9.5.8

Comment: How looks the whole <img>?

Comment: <img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/redakteure/bilder/Diverse/header_0.jpg" alt="Error: no file object" width="1247" height="495">